# how to use mod_rewrite in apache for a rest application

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I'm not very experienced with apache but I have managed to run with the following set up for months on my test box:

```
me@mydev:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ vim 000-default.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

So basically, anytime I create a new folder under /var/www/html, it becomes available in my browser. But now I want to try to do the following:

I've created a new application, with the following structure:

```
/var/www/html/testrestapp/src/public/index.php
```

It works but I have to navigate to:

```
http://localhost/testrestapp/src/public/index.php/hello/sometestname
```

and then the application returns "sometestname"

But I'd like to know how to configure apache so that I can navigate like this:

```
http://localhost/testrestapp/hello/sometestname
```

and get the same results.

This is how I've modified my 000-default.conf file (which is the only file in sites-enabled folder, btw):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory "/var/www/html/testrestapp/">
            RewriteEngine  on
            RewriteBase    /testrestapp/
            RewriteRule    ^src/public/index.php/hello$  hello/  [R]
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

But it's not working for me.  Still getting a 404.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
Apache version is   Apache 2.4.12 on ubuntu

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the Alias and Directory directives (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory)